# How to zoom in a background image to the center of it

Tags: html, css, rotation

How do I zoom in a high quality image, for instance 2000px x 2000px, to the center of a container ? I've tried using `transform: scale ()` but it still makes it scrollable vertically or horizontally. I'm specifically looking for a mobile version. How do I make the image zoomed in centered exactly according to the width of mobile? Using `width: 100%` doesn't help either. And if I define it like in the code below using pixels it is cropped out on mobile. Do I make it exactly width and height or mobile or? I need it to fully cover whole body and be zoomed in exactly in the center of image. Thanks for you answers. Also zoomed quality is really bad even though it is high quality image.

**Basically center and zoom this image [image: bg] so that on mobile it will  cover whole screen, spin and look like this: [image: zoomed bg]**

```
    body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
#wrap {
  transform: scale(2.0);
}
#bg {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 1400px;
  background: url(bg.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-animation: rotation 9s infinite linear;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/tq235155/ I don't think I really understand what you want to achieve from the text. Perhaps show what you want with a few images?

Comment: yeah something like this but not the whole body element because there are several other spinning elements and when I include it in body it starts spinning the wrong thing. I've added some pictures, thanks tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been playing around with this a bit. [This is what I ended up with](https://jsfiddle.net/r9h1zgak/1/).

Here is the logic that I used figuring this out:

- An image rotates around its center.
- If I put the image in a container it will cut a part of the image off. The image will still rotate around the center of the image....But that is not the center of the container anymore.
- Solution: I made the image behave like background: cover; by using min-width: 100%; and min-height: 100%;
- Solution: I centered the image in the container using flexbox.

Another way of centering might be preferable, since the flexbox also affects other children of the container. So any improvements/comments about that would be welcome :).

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" id="image"/>
</div>
```

**css**

```
@keyframes zoom-effect {
 0%   {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);}
 100% {
    transform: scale(4) rotate(360deg);}
}
#wrapper{
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#image{
  z-index: -100;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  animation-name: zoom-effect;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Very nice but there are few problems with this: I still see some blank edges at the start of animation and after 9s animation cuts it self and starts over which isn't really nice.

Comment: I did both on purpose. You can remove the cut by starting out with scale(2). You can loop the effect by making an extra stop in the keyframe. Here is the same thing with a slightly modified keyframe: https://jsfiddle.net/r9h1zgak/2/

Comment: yep works flawlessly now but whenever I do <img src="bg.png"> instead of your long img code it looks like this? https://gyazo.com/558ba3712bd20b202287070e3126a790
how do I solve this? Many thanks by the way

Comment: I can't really tell much about that without the html/css. But by the looks of it there is some unwanted resizing done to the image by the html or css. PS: The image code works exactly the same as an image link.

Comment: <div id="wrapper">
    <img id="image" src="bg.png">
  </div>

that's html and css is exactly the same as yours. Do I need to resize the image in photoshop or something? dimensions are 2500x2500 I believe, is it because of that? Sorry if I sound retarded, it annoys me so bad :D

Comment: Does adding : height: auto !important;
  width: auto !important; to #image help?

Comment: Hmm idk then, got a JSFiddle with the issue to play around with?

Comment: no need for js probably, it would simply copy your code, here's the bg image it self if you can play with it: http://www105.zippyshare.com/v/d9JnqwH5/file.html

Comment: I don't know why, but removing min-width: 100% from the #image seems to resolve the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/r9h1zgak/3/. I am not sure if this is going to have other consequences.

Comment: yep that worked thank you, last question: on mobile when I set wrapper width: 100% and height: 100% so it covers whole screen it appears to be literally full height of the image and becomes huge and scrollable, how do I fit it into mobile screen to the center of it without using height: 700px; or so?

Comment: If it is full screen you can try to use height: 100vh; (vh = viewport height). Otherwise you d have to define the containers size by fixed positioning or define a pixel height.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `background-size: 200%` combined with `background-position: -50%, -50%` or a similar proportion (300% size vs. -100% position offset)

Example:

```css
.x {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/400x400/fa0);
  background-size: 300%;
  background-position: -100%, -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
</div>
```

About rotation: You can rotate the whole thing, but not the background image alone, so you have to use two DIVs: Put one rotating div into another (smaller) div that has `overflow: hidden`.The rotating DIV has to have `position: absolute` and `z-index: -1` to remain in the background.

Here's that situation in action:

```css
.y {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.x {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  left: -200px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/400x400/fa0);
  background-size: 300%;
  background-position: -100%, -100%;
  animation: move 5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes move {
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="y">
    Any content here.
  <div class="x">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please note the most recent addition to my answer, which does eactly what you want (if i understood you correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Set `width: 100%` and remove `background-size: contain`:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/987n5Luz/)

```css
#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1000x1000);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
```

and if you want to use these styles for the body, add `background-attachment: fixed`:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y38a3jw9/)

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1000x1000);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: thank you! works fine on desktop but on mobile it still isn't centered. Also is the anyway to replace transform: scale(); because everything becomes zoomed in on mobile and I can simply zoom out using fingers and it becomes cropped out, how to make it cover whole screen? Because it is rotating.

Comment: Could you attach your html to the first post?